# Track SharePoint Workflow Status

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, workflow, sharepoint-workflow

I need to create a SharePoint workflow to keep track of other workflows which had error status. I am not sure where to start from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint list stores the status of workflow as a separate column in the list list itself

You Can a Create a workflow on the list with condition on workflow you want to track.............just copy the item to another list if status is not `Complete`.It should work ...

Comment: Thanks, I just realized the value for workflow status column is not in textual format. Instead it uses numerical value. I googled and found below values:
Status                     -Value
Not Started                 0
Failed on Start             1
In Progress                 2
Error Occurred              3
Canceled                    4
Completed                   5
Failed on Start (retrying)  6
Error Occurred (retrying)   7
Canceled                   15
Approved                   16
Rejected                   17